# ngClass: Check if input has value with angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, input

I've got an `angular` `component` for an `input` with a floating `label`. I toggle a `boolean` variable for setting the `class` on the `input` wrapper to make the floating `animation` for the `label` with `angular` `(blur)` and `(focus)` on the `input` element. Now this works fine, when I click in the `input`, the `label` animates up and when I leave the `input` it animates back down. My only problem is, when I type a value in the `input` and leave it, the `label` should stay floated above the `input`. At the moment, it animates back down and overlapps the `value`. How can I detect for example in my `ngClass`, if `isFocused` is `true` **or** the `label` has a `value`, to keep the `class`?

Here is my code. On stackoverflow snippet, there is only `angularjs` supported, so I was not able to make a snippet here, sry for that!

HTML:

```
<div class="my-input" [ngClass]="isFocused ? 'state-my-input--active' : ''">
  <div class="my-input__wrapper">
    <label class="my-input__label">Label</label>
    <input type="text" class="my-input__input" (blur)="isFocused = false" (focus)="isFocused = true">
  </div>
</div>
```

SCSS:

```
.my-input {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  margin-top: 50px;
}

.my-input__wrapper {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  position: relative;
}

.my-input__label {
  bottom: 8px;
  color: blue;
  font-size: 14px;
  position: absolute;
  transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

.my-input__input {
  border: none;
  border-bottom: 2px solid darkgray;
  color: blue;
  transition: border-color 180ms linear;
}

.state-my-input--active {
  .my-input__wrapper {
    .my-input__label {
      transform: translateY(-15px);
      cursor: default;
    }

    .my-input__input {
      border-bottom-color: blue;
    }
  }
}
```

JS:

```
import { Component, OnInit } from "@angular/core";

@Component({
    selector: "my-input",
    templateUrl: "./my-input.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./my-input.component.scss"]
})
export class MyInputComponent implements OnInit {
    isFocused: boolean = false;

    constructor() {}

    ngOnInit() {}
}
```

Comment: Try instead with `[class.state-my-input--active]="isFocused"`

Comment: If `label` has a value Or `Input` has a value u mean ?

Comment: @selemmn If input has a value

Comment: @MrBuggy u had already an answer..

Comment: @selemmn Yes, saw it. I found a solution based on one of the anwers! thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

first define `[(ngModel)]` in your input. then try to add class by using this approach.

```
<div class="my-input" [ngClass]="{'state-my-input--active': isFocused || someValue}">
  <div class="my-input__wrapper">
    <label class="my-input__label">Label</label>
    <input type="text" class="my-input__input" [(ngModel)]="someValue" (blur)="isFocused = false" (focus)="isFocused = true">
  </div>
</div>
```

or you can use angular material for floating labels.to see examples click [here](https://material.angular.io/components/input/overview)

Comment: This answer helped me to solve my issue! With adding a `[(ngModel)]` to the input and change the condition in the `[ngClass]` to this: `[ngClass]="{'state-my-input--active': isFocused || someValue}"` it works as excpected! The labels floats when above when empty and focus, floats back if leaving empty and stays floated if leaving with a value in the input! Thanks!

Answer (score 4):

Try:

```
[ngClass]="{'state-my-input--active': isFocused}"
```

Comment: This does not work, it's just another way to write the condition for focus or not. With this solution, the label floats back when I leave the input and overlapps my typed value. My question was, how to keep the floated label above the input, if there is a value in the input, also when leaving it.

Answer (score 1):

To also get the value in your condition simply use (of course you has to define and bind value first:

```
[ngClass]="{'state-my-input--active': isFocused || value != ''}"
```

or

```
[class.state-my-input--active]="isFocused || value != ''"
```

see https://angular.io/api/common/NgClass

Comment: I tried the first solution with `[ngClass]` in combination with an `[(ngModel)]` on the `input`. I also had to change the condition from`value != ''` to `value != undefined`, because with your solution the label was always above the input, don't know why. At the moment, when I click in the input, the label floats above the input, I can type a value and leave the input and it stays. When I go back to the input and delete the value and leave the input, the label stays still above the input, it doesn't float back. Any idea why?

Comment: Maybe this time the value is not undefined but empty. Do you try a combination of "value != ''" and "value != undefined"? Probably you has to test "undefined" because your value is not initialized with null or a empty string.

Comment: I tried the combination, but didn't work. Check the answer which is marked as correct, there is my solution which worked for ngModel and focus

Comment: Checkout https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-pwbmff for me it´s working.